# PHP Undefined function when calling function from included file inside class method

Tags: php, function, methods, scope

So, i created the view method :

```php
<?php
namespace MYAPP\Controller;
/**
 * Site controller
 */
class Site extends Controller
{
    // ... other method and variable
    /**
     * Load theme file
     * @param $part string Theme Part
     * @param $bind_param array Binding variable
     **/
    private function loadTheme(string $part, array $bind_param=[]){
        $that = $this;
        function getAllCategories(){
            global $that;
            // Returning all categories
        }
        extract(array_merge($this->config, $bind_param));
        include $this->theme_root.'/'.$part; // I want to call getAllCategories function from this file
    }
}
```

When i call `getAllCategories` from included file:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function getAllCategories() in .....
```

So how i can make `getAllCategories` accessible from included file from that method...

Comment: Why are you nesting your functions like that? There are occasionally uses for it, but mostly it just causes problems

Comment: @Dharman i know, inside the `loadTheme` method i created function `getAllCategories` and also include template part... But why Inside the included template part, i can not call `getAllCategories` function, i think included file is same scope as `getAllCategories` function?

Comment: @ADyson i want the `getAllCategories` function is accessible from included file in `loadTheme` method...

Comment: Ok well, I'll ask again: with that objective in mind, why did you nest the getAllCategories function inside another function? What were you hoping to achieve by that? Do you realise that the function is only created when the loadTheme() function is run? And even then, it won't be a member of the class...you'd only be able to access it from within loadTheme(), or using global scope. It makes no sense to use a nested function here - that's your problem.